# iPhone-style sliding views in HTML/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a mobile website in HTML/HTML5. This is NOT an iOS app but I would like to provide the look and feel of an app. I found nice toolkits like iWebKit for the CSS.

Now I want to implement to standard sliding view: when you click an item in a list, the viewport slides horizontally to show the details of the item. Then you can move back to the list (without losing your scrolling position, etc.)

Is there a HTML/JS framework I can use the do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean jQuery Mobile collapsibles? Upon clicking, they can expand to reveal more detail.
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

If you want something more akin to a means of navigating to more specific pages, jQuery Mobile offers support for remembering pages you've been to as well, so users of your mobile app can efficiently navigate back and go to the home page, as detailed here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html. This feature is automatically set in jQuery Mobile websites.

Comment: No, I believe they're looking for something similar to a [navigation view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what they're looking for.